# If $Y$ is a regular, then $\delta(X,Y)$ with compact-open topology is regular

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, compactness, axiom-of-choice

Suppose $Y$ is regular.

Let $f^*$ be point in $δ(X,Y)$ and $\{f:f(K)∈G\}$ open set such that
$f^*∈\{f:f(K)⊆G\}$.

Since $f^* (K)⊆G$, and ($Y$ regular) then $∀y∈f^* (K), ∃v_y$ open set such that $y∈v_y⊆(v_y ) ̅⊆G$.

Since $f^*$ is continuous, then $f^* (K)$ is compact, and the open covering $\{v_y:y∈f^* (K)\}$ must have a finite subcover. The union of this subcover $V$ will have the property
$f^* (K)⊆V⊆V ̅⊆G$

Hence $f^*∈\{f:f(K)⊆V\}$.

> If $g∉\{f:f(K)∈\bar{V} \}$, then $∃x∈K∋g(x)∉\bar{V}$.Thus,
> $π_x^{-1}(X| \bar{V})=\{f:f(x)∈X | \bar{V} \}$
> is an open set in the “point-open” topology and
> hence also in the “compact-open” topology which contains $g$ is
> disjoint of the form $\{f:f(K)⊆V\}$.
>
> Hence $Cl(\{f:f(K)⊆V\}) ⊆\{f:f(K)∈\bar{V} \}⊆\{f:f(K)∈G\}$.

Let $f^*$ be contained in a general open set $\mathcal{G}^*$ which then contains
a basis open set
$\{f:f(K_1 )⊆G_1 \}∩…∩\{f:f(K_n )⊆G_n \}⊆\mathcal{G}^*$
where $f^* (K_i )⊆G_i$ that is, a basis open set containing $f^*$. By the above
construction, the set
$V^*=\{f:f(K_1 )⊆V_1 \}∩…∩\{f:f(K_n )⊆V_n\}$
is an open set such that $f^*∈V^*⊆(V^* ) ̅⊆\mathcal{G}^*$.

I am trying to understand the above proof. I understand most of the proof what we are trying to do but I fail to understand the quoted part and how it is related to the rest of the proof. Could you please explain to me the quoted part. [Another presentation of the prrof.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z4Rj.png)

Comment: Define $\delta(X,Y)$?

Comment: $f(K) \in V$ makes no sense. You mean $f[K] \subseteq V$ perhaps? I use $[]$ for images of subsets, $()$ for images of points in the domain, etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It's a common practice to denote the image of a subset $A$ of the domain of $f$ as $f(A)$.

Comment: @jjagmath It might be common but I find it confusing. And $\in V$ instead of $\subseteq V$ (or $\subset V$ ) is not common but just plain wrong.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Just saying that since it's a common notation (even if you don't like it), you should have focused your comment on the wrong part: to use $\in$ instead of $\subseteq$.

Comment: I mention the wrongness of $f(K) \in V$. The $\in$ is nonsense here and the $f(K)$ should  really be $f[K]$ for clarity. We *can* have maps with sets as input parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quoted part just shows that $\{f : f[K] \subseteq \overline{V}\}$ is closed in the compact-open topology. It does this by sowing that its complement is even pointwise-open so in particular compact open. As $\{f: f[K]\subseteq V\}$ is a subset of this closed set, the *closure* of it is also a subset of $\{f: f[K]\subseteq \overline{V}\}$ and finally that set is itself trivially (by definition) a subset of $\{f: f[K]\subseteq G\}$ as $\overline{V}\subseteq G$. Etc.

So for the *subbasic* sets of the compact-open topology we can find, for each point, some *subbasic* open set that contains it and whose closure sits inside that first subbasic open set; it's a first step towards doing this for *all* open sets (as we need to do; do we reduce this to the base generated by the subbasic sets at the end).

Comment: Here is the orginal proof https://i.imgur.com/ZVVXlnj.png

Comment: @gbd You already had it in the question.

Comment: My question is about this part https://i.imgur.com/hrBrxlb.png. Is it trying to prove that $C(\{f:f(K)⊆V\}) ⊆\{f:f(K)\subseteq C(V) \}$?

Comment: @gbd a set $C$ is closed in any space iff for each $p\notin C$ we can find an open set containing $p$ and disjoint from $C$. That fact is applied there.